# Calculate sine and cosine in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to use the sine and cosine of an angle. How can I calculate it?

I need something like this:

```
var a = 40 (angle)
var sina = sin(a) -> in order to have in output a number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
print(Math.cos(40 * Math.PI/180)) // Client-side
print(ee.Number(40 * Math.PI/180).cos()) // Server-side (For ee.Number and ee.Image)
```